# Get posts of user's friends and order them by datetime of colomns

Tags: php, mysql

I Have two tables the first called 'posts' and the second called 'friends'
I want to get the posts that it's 'publisher' column is exist in 'friends' table ( that's mean to get friends posts) than i want to order it by datetime column that found in 'posts' table.

What I have tried is :

```
$fetch_fr_result = $conn->query("SELECT frid FROM friends WHERE username='$userusername'");
while ($fetch_fr_send = $fetch_fr_result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
$fetch_fr_id = $fetch_fr_send->frid;

$fetch_fr_data_result = $conn->query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE id='$fetch_fr_id'");
$fetch_fr_data_send = $fetch_fr_data_result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$fetch_fr_data_username = $fetch_fr_data_send->username;

$fetch_posts_result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE publisher='$fetch_fr_data_username' ORDER BY orderdate DESC LIMIT 5");

while ($fetch_posts_send = $fetch_posts_result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
$fetch_posts_msg = $fetch_posts_send->thetext;
$fetch_posts_time = $fetch_posts_send->time;
if (!empty($fetch_posts_msg)){
echo '<div class="posttext">' . $fetch_posts_msg . '</div> - ' . $fetch_posts_time;
}
}
}
```

The problem in this code is : 
Getting each friend then get friend's posts then order them by time , but I want to order all friend's posts by time !

Tell me what to do please ?

Comment: Can you show us your table structures? Btw what you want here is to join tables.

Comment: Here is the tables' pictures : http://imgur.com/4mFKkTM  | http://imgur.com/GDHJfAI

Comment: And the users table please.

Comment: There are two images in the previous comment :)

Comment: Yes for the tables "posts" and "friends", not the "users" table.

Comment: It's here http://imgur.com/CbGiZKs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I have misunderstood your question, but this might give you what you want. If not tell me whats wrong and I'll try to solve it.

```
$fetch_result = $conn->query('
    SELECT 
        `p`.thetext,
        `p`.time
    FROM 
        `friends` as f,
        `users` as u,
        `posts` as p
    WHERE 
        `f`.frid = `u`.id /* join friends id with users table */
    AND 
        `p`.publisher = `u`.username /* join friends username with posts table */
    AND 
        `f`.username = "' . $userusername . '" 
    ORDER BY 
        `p`.orderdate DESC
');
```

And I would advice you to use the userid as a foreign key in other tables, not the username. And you should change the datatypes to use something that fits better. There are too many varchar(1000) in your tables.

Comment: Thanks for your advices , for my problem , I have faced the same problem see the images here : http://imgur.com/rdqCUu4

Comment: The problem is in the ordering of posts , it gets user friends' posts and working as well but the order of all posts (not each friend posts) is not working :(

Comment: Can you run the query I wrote in a sql client and change $userusername with an actual username and send a screenshot of the result?

Comment: Seems like you want to order by the `time` field? What kind of data do you store in the time field in the posts table?

Comment: The time of the 'time' column is time() of php

Comment: First of all the `time` column should be an int not varchar if you're planning on using unix timestamp. And in the picture you showed there is both unix timestamps, and sometimes there is the date format YY-DD-MM HH:MM:SS. This is a mess. You need to clean this up. Stick with either datetime or unix timestamp (php's time()). Then after you have done that, you can order by the `time` column instead of the `orderdate` column.

Comment: And what is the difference of the `time` column and `orderdate` column?

Comment: the 'time' column is not using for ordering posts but it's only displays with the posts like the image , the ordering of the posts is depends on `orderdate` colomn with the time format `YY-DD-MM HH:MM:SS`

Comment: But why do you have both? Why not just use one?

Comment: And if you could do one more thing. Run this query https://pastebin.com/aaNBYAPS (replace SOMEUSERNAME with an actual username) and send a screenshot of the result.

Comment: As you can see the query is working as expected, the orderdate field is being ordered correctly. Newest first.

Comment: See , It's working because we are fetching the posts of one user , but if you run the query using the php's `while (){ }` it will get the ordered posts of each user , what i want is getting the posts of all friends then order it (ordering all friends' posts not ordering each friend' posts).

Comment: So the query I wrote don't give you all posts of all friends to the user you replace SOMEUSERNAME with?

Comment: Wait to check please

Comment: Thanks a lot for your assistment , the query is working but the problem is in the `time` column , thanks a lot :*

Comment: No problem, glad to be able to help :)